# MySql Trigger Syntax Error 1064 Empty Single Quotes

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute trigger statement in MySql 5.1.41 but i am getting an error which is beyond my comprehension. Any help will be appreciated.

Following is the trigger code:

```
create TRIGGER populate_modality_trigger AFTER INSERT on series
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE x int;

select count(*) into x from lu_modality_alias l WHERE l.modality=NEW.modality;
IF (x  =0 OR x is NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO lu_modality_alias 
    set modality = NEW.modality,
    modality_alias  = NEW.modality
;
END if;
end;
```

When I run above code, I get following error:

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

The interesting thing is that when i execute the same code from Naviacat query editor, it runs successfully and trigger is created.
But the same fails from phpMyAdmin sql.

Comment: you need to change your delimiter. The first ; is ending the CREATE statement

Comment: thanks alot, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter character so the MySql parser doesn't end the CREATE statement parsing at the first semi-colon

```
delimiter //

create TRIGGER populate_modality_trigger AFTER INSERT on series
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE x int;

select count(*) into x from lu_modality_alias l WHERE l.modality=NEW.modality;
IF (x  =0 OR x is NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO lu_modality_alias 
    set modality = NEW.modality,
    modality_alias  = NEW.modality
;
END if;
end //

delimiter ;
```